# In the context of C++, what is an "implementation"?

Tags: c++, standard-library

I am reading Accelerated C++ and there are lines written there about standard header

> It is worth noting that although we refer to our own headers as header files, we refer to the
>   implementation-supplied headers as standard headers rather than standard header files. The
>   reason is that header files are genuine files in every C++ implementation, but system headers
>   need not be implemented as files.

My first question is that if we are running windows OS and in one hand we have [**codeblocks**](http://www.codeblocks.org/) (GNU compiler) and in second we have **turbo c++**. So do we consider them as separate implementation?

My second question is that how actually these standard headers are implemented?

Comment: Code::Blocks is an [IDE, not a compiler](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-General#Q:_What_Code::Blocks_is_not.3F) (thus not an implementation of C++).

Comment: Please mention the reason for downvote.

Comment: @melpomene thats what i am asking what's actually implementation??

Comment: No, that's all orthogonal. Code Blocks is an IDE that may work with various c++ compiler implementations like Turbo c++.

Comment: @Rouftantical That's not what you're asking in the post above.

Comment: @melpomene oh please don't say this

Comment: @Rouftantical Asking why pears aren't apples is pretty useless, isn't it?

Comment: @Rouftantical: Just one reason of many: no research effort displayed.

Comment: Yes, GCC and Turbo C++ are two different implementations. Their standard library implementations are implemented in code. For example, GCC uses [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3) and [glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git).

Comment: @melpomene but Cornstalks said that these are different implementation?

Comment: @Rouftantical What do you mean, "but"? I never said they weren't. In fact, I haven't said anything about GCC in these comments.

Comment: @melpomene but you were turning things around in diplomatic manner.

Comment: Granted the author got a bit confused about code blocks, but I think they asked a good question. Someone was able to provide a good answer that I learned something from, and I'm sure others well as well. I think the down voting is a bit harsh.

Comment: @NirFriedman thanks for standing with me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point the author is making is that the compiler, should it wish to do so, could implement `#include <string>` internally in the compiler, without there ever being any file called `string` in the system that compiles your code. In reality, I'm not aware of any compiler that DOES implement this, but it's certainly viable from what the C++ standards perspective.

Each compiler vendor, such as GNU and Free Software Foundation for gcc, the people at Illinois University behind clang, the people at Microsoft, Borland, IBM, Intel, etc that produce a compiler will produce "an implementation" of a compiler. If I write my own C++ compiler  that will be an implementation. I happen to have my own compiler for the language Pascal (written in C++ and using LLVM as the backend) - which is an implementation of the language Pascal - and like all implementations, it follows the standard, but has some "implementation defined" features. All implementations will have some things that are "based on what the implementor choose to do", for several possible reasons:

1. The standard is not specific: size of `int` or Pascal's `integer` is not specified beyond "it must be at least this big ...", so as long as the minimum criteria is fulfilled, the implementor can do what he/she/they chooses.
2. Extensions - something that goes beyond the standard. Often the standard has restrictions or missing functionality that the implementor may decide to "improve" (this does make the implementation "non-standard", but if the extension doesn't alter the behaviour of standard compliant code, it's "safe" to add) [for example, Pascal doesn't have "names on files", so a Pascal program can't create a file by a particular name - most implementations do have SOME way to create a file by a particular name as an extension]
3. Standard specifies "implementation defined behaviour" - similar to non-specific, the standard can say that "this is up to the implementor to do as she/he/they wish".

Comment: Wow, yeah, that's remarkably pedantic of the author.

Comment: So its safe to assume that each compiler is a different implementation?

Comment: @Rouftantical: By definition that is true. Each compiler is part of a distinct implementation of C++.

Comment: Yes, even if I take the source of clang, and recompile it with a single small change, and publish that one change [under the same license as clang], it is a different implementation - technically, version 5.0 and 5.0.1 are also different implementations - but their overall behaviour is most likely identical.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr an "implementation" here is an implementation of the theoretical abstract machine called "C++"**

You are confusing IDEs/editors and compilers.

GCC 5.1 is a compiler/linker/toolchain/standard library implementation ("implementation" overall).

As is Visual C++ 2015 (though this nomenclature also extends to the IDE itself; thanks, Microsoft!).

As is your Turbo C++ product that is older than C++ and older than you are.

CodeBlocks is an IDE that *invokes* a toolchain. It may or may not be the same one as you're using with your ancient Turbo C++ installation, though I very much doubt it since your Turbo C++ requires a DOS emulator to run (*ROFL*).

Comment: Inb4 he's older than Turbo.

Comment: Isn't Visual C++ the "compiler/linker/toolchain/standard library implementation", whereas Visual Studio is an IDE (for multiple programming languages)?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Yeah, I suppose that's closer, though Visual C++ itself is still billed as an IDE. Unfortunately it's hard to be exact because MS literally don't distinguish between IDE and compiler. You're right in that Visual Studio is a suite (of IDEs and implementations), though.

Comment: TBH the whole point of an IDE is that it's Integrated. A compiler which merely ships with an editor tailored to editing code isn't really an IDE. That said, it's embarrassing how poor the VC++ integration with the Windows SDK is. (Yes, I know, different groups at Microsoft - OS and tools)

Comment: @MSalters: Integration doesn't require tight coupling, though. That is, integration in usage and integration in implementation are two different things. Look at Eclipse, CodeBlocks, all of that: you can use whatever compiler you want. Sure, to a degree you can hack it about in VS, too, but the fact that the VC++ compiler is literally in the same package as the GUI tells you everything.

Comment: I know what a hack it becomes, non-standard compilers in Visual Studio. Just look at Qt. Visual Studio knows almost all compiler and linker options, and can even relate them. (E.g. LTCG works quite well, demand-loaded libraries too). But where it really shines is in the debugger.